# Find a unit vector in which the directional derivative equals zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

> Find a unit vector u in which the directional derivative of $f(x,y)=\ln(1-x^2-y^2)$  at ($\frac{1}{2} ,\frac{1}{2}$) is zero

$f_x=\frac{-2x}{1-x^2-y^2}$ and $f_y=\frac{-2y}{1-x^2-y^2}$

Giving us the gradient at $\frac{1}{2} ,\frac{1}{2}$ to be $-2,-2$

How do I now find the unit vector?

Answer (score 1):

The directional derivative $\nabla_vf$ of a function $f$ in direction of a vector $v = (v_x, v_y)^\top$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) can be obtained by

$$\nabla_vf = \langle \operatorname{grad} f , v\rangle$$

So you have to find a vector $v$ such that

$$\langle \operatorname{grad} f , v\rangle = 0$$

Thus, in your case:

$$-2v_x  -2v_y = 0$$

This is satisfied by all vectors of the form $v = (t,-t)^\top$ with $t \in \mathbb{R}$. So a corresponding unit vector is e.g. $u = \left({1 \over\sqrt{2}},-{1 \over \sqrt{2}}\right)^\top$, because $\Vert u\Vert  = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Directional derivative along $\vec v$ is:

$\nabla f\cdot \vec v$

This being zero means to find any vector $\vec v$ perpendicular to the gradient then you can normalize $\vec u=\vec v/|\vec v|$ it to make it a unit vector.